# Why is there a comma at the end of this Sentence?

Tags: commas, sentence-ends

Why is there a comma after palate in the sentence below?

> Many dairy foods come in low-fat version, and though not all of them may be pleasing to the palate, some are.

Comment: Because that’s how it’s said. Do you have some source that is telling you otherwise that you could please provide us with?

Comment: no, i know the sentence is correct, but what is the grammer rule that caused a comma to placed after palate in that sentence?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't what I meant. I meant that the reason we place the comma there is because that is the cadence native speakers apply there. We have a little pause in our speech so we put a comma there so that readers can recreate in their minds what we said aloud. Commas are far more a matter of style and clarity than ever they are of grammar. It is possible that some language primers for foreign speakers have some sort of rule for this. You may be interested in our sister-site [ell.se]. I have deliberately omitted commas from this posting. ***All*** punctuation is a style matter.

Comment: I can hear the pause in my mind when reading that sentence I just thought that there might be a rule to it. Thanks I'll check the link

Comment: I do believe there exist guidelines about introductory  clauses like this, but I've been having a hard time coming up with a prior question that talks about this in a way that will answer your question for you. If I do find one, I'll let you now.

Comment: All punctuation is indeed a matter of style, but punctuation is for writing, not speaking, so where we pause in reading something aloud is a poor guide to comma usage. Punctuation guides readers in making the correct parse of linear text that represents non-linear syntax. There are numerous style guides, and they don't all agree on everything, but one common rule is in force here: follow a sufficiently long introductory adverbial clause with a comma. This separates a subordinate clause and idea (some foods aren't pleasing) from a main clause and idea (still some are pleasing).

Comment: There isn't a comma at the end of the sentence. There's a comma at the end of a _subordinate clause_, which is perfectly normal and common. If anything, the comma is _before_ the sentence, since the main clause (which is the necessary crux of the sentence) comes _after_ the comma. Compare “Despite this, some low-fat dairy foods are pleasing to the palate”, where the implied repeated information has been restored to the main clause and excluded from the previous clauses. That shows more clearly that the comma isn't at the end, but almost at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the usage of comma.

From Purdue OWL:

> Use a comma near the end of a sentence to separate contrasted coordinate elements or to indicate a distinct pause or shift

Reference: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/

Comment: Yup, that seems right. The comma in this sentence is used to separate contrasted coordinate elements.